# Issue with USB Permissions on Android 9 using usb-serial-for-android library

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, android-permissions

StackOverflow community!

I'm facing a problem while working with a device through the RS485 port on an Odroid N2 board running Android 9. I'm using a USB/RS485 adapter and the usb-serial-for-android library to communicate with the device using the Modbus RTU protocol.

I'm encountering an issue with obtaining USB permissions in my Unity application on Android 9. When attempting to connect to the device, I receive the error "USB_PERMISSION denied" and the exception "java.lang.SecurityException: User has not given permission to the device."

Here's what I've already done:

1. Modified the Manifest and added all necessary permissions.

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   ```

   ```
    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"/>
    <application
        android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        </activity>
    </application>
   ```
2. Ensured that the application has Superuser rights.
3. Enabled USB debugging mode in developer options.
4. Adjusted device permissions (read and write allowed).
   [i've changed device rights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1V1hL.png)
5. Using the usb-serial-for-android library along with the corresponding Java plugin for integration.
   (i am using this code [USB Serial Driver Java Plugin not working in Unity Android build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64633131/usb-serial-driver-java-plugin-not-working-in-unity-android-build))

Despite all my efforts, the pop-up window requesting permission to use the USB device doesn't appear. Android seems to be denying permission for the USB device usage. How can I overcome this issue and obtain the necessary permissions for interacting with the USB device in my Unity application on Android 9?

I would appreciate any guidance or solutions to this problem. Thank you!

Comment: Is the device already opened.  Often this error occurs when the OS opens the port on startup or the port is being used for a printer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the solution was a little surprising to me. I tried to use the /dev/ttyS0 port because my device showed it to me as soon as the one opened. But the guys from the odroid forum suggested that I didn't have the ftdi driver installed. So they were right.

Follow this steps to check if you have this driver:

1. `$ adb remount`
2. `adb shell`
3. `# vi /vendor/etc/init/hw/init.odroid.board.rc`
4. You will probably receive lines like this:

   - on post-fs-data
   - insmod /vendor/lib/modules/btrtl.ko
   - insmod /vendor/lib/modules/btusb.ko
   - insmod /vendor/lib/modules/hid-multitouch.ko
   - insmod /vendor/lib/modules/dwav-usb-mt.ko
   - insmod /vendor/lib/modules/ftdi_sio.ko // I didn't have this line
5. If you don't have "insmod /vendor/lib/modules/ftdi_sio.ko" it can be your problem (so it was mine). To add this line use this:
6. `$ adb remount`
7. `$ adb shell`
8. `# su`      // if it is needed
9. `# echo "insmod /vendor/lib/modules/ftdi_sio.ko" >>  /vendor/etc/init/hw/init.odroid.board.rc`

So after all this steps I can see the /dev/ttyUSB0 port and connect to it.

- https://forum.odroid.com/viewtopic.php?f=178&p=378391#p378391
- https://forum.odroid.com/viewtopic.php?t=22911